# PostgreSQL 9.5.15 - Left join with huge table taking time

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I need your suggestion on the below query performance issue.

```
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tableA(  id bigint NOT NULL,  second_id bigint );

  CREATE INDEX idx_tableA_id  ON tableA  USING btree (id);

  CREATE INDEX idx_tableA_second_id  ON tableA  USING btree (second_id);
```

here the table A having 100K records.

```
CREATE TABLE tableB(  id bigint NOT NULL);

CREATE INDEX idx_tableB_id  ON tableB  USING btree (id);
```

But the table B having the 145GB volume of data.

If i execute the query with one left join like below,

```
select a.id from table A left join table B on B.id = A.id
```

or

```
select a.id from table A left join table B on B.d_id = A.Second_id
```

getting the data quicker. But when i combine both the LEFT JOIN, then the query taking 30 minutes to query the records.

```
SELECT a.id 
FROM tableA A LEFT JOIN tableB B on B.id = A.id 
LEFT JOIN tableB B1 on B1.id = A.second_id;
```

Got the indexes on the respective columns. Any other performance suggestions to reduce the execution time.

### VERSION: "PostgreSQL 9.5.15 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit"

```
Execution plan
Hash Right Join  (cost=18744968.20..108460708.81 rows=298384424 width=8) (actual time=469896.453..1290666.446 rows=26520 loops=1) 
Hash Cond: (tableB.id = tableA.id)
->  Seq Scan on tableB ubp1  (cost=0.00..63944581.96 rows=264200740 width=8) (actual time=127.504..1182339.167 rows=268297289 loops=1)
Filter: (company_type_id = 2)
Rows Removed by Filter: 1409407086
->  Hash  (cost=18722912.16..18722912.16 rows=1764483 width=8) (actual time=16564.303..16564.303 rows=26520 loops=1)
Buckets: 2097152  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 17420kB
->  Merge Join  (cost=6035.58..18722912.16 rows=1764483 width=8) (actual time=37.964..16503.057 rows=26520 loops=1)
->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.86..18686031.22 rows=1752390 width=8) (actual time=0.019..16412.634 rows=26520 loops=1)
->  Index Scan using idx_tableA_id on tableA A  (cost=0.29..94059.62 rows=26520 width=16) (actual time=0.013..69.016 rows=26520 loops=1)
->  Index Scan using idx_tableB_id on tableB B  (cost=0.58..699.36 rows=169 width=8) (actual time=0.458..0.615 rows=0 loops=26520)
Index Cond: (tableA.id = tableB.second_id)
Filter: (company_type_id = 2)
Rows Removed by Filter: 2
->  Sort  (cost=6034.21..6100.97 rows=26703 width=8) (actual time=37.941..54.444 rows=26520 loops=1)
Rows Removed by Filter: 105741
Planning time: 0.878 ms
Execution time: 1290674.154 ms
```

Thanks and Regards,
Thiru.M

Comment: Dear lord... 145GB... Nevertheless : do you need all B and B1 data? Line and columns? Can you update your postgres version? Usage of pgpartman maybe is a solution too.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` and `create table` statements for all tables involved.

Comment: If you are joining to the same table with two different aliases, then that is what your example should show.

Comment: If "B" and "B1" each return multiple rows for each A.id, then what you get for each A.id when you join to both simultaneously will be have as many rows as the product of those two row counts.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect

- B1.second_id either does not have an index
- B1.second_id is not unique (or a primary key)
- B1.second_id is part of a multi-column index where it is not the first column in the index

If you have an index on that column, you could also try moving the indexes to a different volume so that it's not in contention with the main data retrieval.

Run EXPLAIN on your query to verify that indexes are being used instead of falling back to a sequential scan on a 145GB volume.

You also didn't mention how much RAM your database has available. If your settings combined with your query is making the system swap, you could see precipitous drops in performance as well.

Comment: Hi Miles, I have updated my question with explain plan as well.  Are you able to help on this.

Comment: Where is this coming from? `company_type_id`

Comment: This company id filter is from the tableB [Large table].